# Fixed Convolutional Kernel as a Filter for Image Preprocessing

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I modulated a filter for image enhancement and processed the enhanced image into a neural network, resulting in a significant improvement in the results. Now I save this filter in npy format and read it in the neural network. I treat it as a convolutional kernel with fixed parameters and place it in the first layer of the network, leaving the other structures unchanged. I don't know why the final result did not improve.

I have added these lines of code to the first layer of the network for image enhancement. The npy format filter is a shape of 223 * 223 * 3 * 1

```
g_filter = np.load('g_filter_process/g223.npy')
g_filter = np.array(g_filter,dtype=np.float32)
g_filter = tf.constant(g_filter)
img_pad = tf.pad(img_input, [[0, 0], [111, 111], [111, 111], [0, 0]], mode='REFLECT')  
img_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(img_pad, g_filter, 1, 'VALID',name = 'gabor')
```

Comment: are you sure that you want all of that padding? 111 seems excessive